# Markers in google map takes long time for updating

Tags: android, performance, google-maps

I'm using google maps to mark several positions which is updated at equal time intervals. There is no problem with markers they working fine. But when updating the markers and when the map is zoomed in, the markers disappears and takes long time to get marked in the map. Its looks as if the people had disappeared all of a sudden.

I'm using counter class to call update marker worker thread at equal intervals.

**Counter class**

```
     public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        new MapUpdater().execute("");
        resetTimer();                 
    }

    public void resetTimer()
    {
        counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);
            counter.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

 }
```

**MapUpdater Async task**

```
     private class MapUpdater extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      Log.d("ASYN", "STARTED");
      map.invalidate();
         itemizedoverlay.doPopulate();
      }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       updatePosition();
       return "finished";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         itemizedoverlay.doPopulate();
         Log.d("ASYN", "ENDED");
   }
```

}

**updatePosition() method**

```
     public void updatePosition()
     {
    try{
                lat_coordinates[]= CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/return_coord.php", postParameters);
                lng_coordinates[]= CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/return_coord.php", postParameters);
     }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
            itemizedoverlay.removeAllOverlay();
            itemizedoverlay.doPopulate();

             try{
                for(int i=0; i<lat_coordinates.length; i++)
                 {
                     GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat_coordinates[i]*1E6),(int)(lng_coordinates[i]*1E6));
                     try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat_coordinates[i],lng_coordinates[i], 1);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("update", "no format exception");
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("update", e.toString());
                    }
                     overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"title",addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                 }
             }catch(NullPointerException e){
                 e.getStackTrace();

             }
             finally{
                overlayList.add(itemizedoverlay);
         }

}
```

Any suggestions? It take long time to update that it spoils the entire application.

Thanks

Comment: May be your GPS or internet connection will be slow, actually loading and zooming a map and then marking a location takes some time, but if takes too much time then may be you have slow internet  connection service, in my project i am marking 15 to 20 location along with uploading pic but it doesn't take too much time

Comment: I'm not using GPS service and I'm using broadband internet connection. BTW if the internet connection is slow it would take long time to get response. I'm removing markers only after getting response. But why does the marker disappears even when it runs in separate thread :(

Comment: @Robo Techi And in your project if you are updating markers at regular time and they don't disappear may I know how you do it?